# Wifi communication between Raspberry Pi 2 and BeagleBone Black

Tags: raspberry-pi2, beagleboneblack, robotics

I have a raspi 2 with a WiFi dongle and is setup to act as an access point/router. I also have 2 BeagleBone Blacks that also have WiFi dongles and they are connected to the raspi's network as well as a 9 axis sensor (accelerometer, gyro, etc). But I am unsure on how to send data from one board to another. And it has to be wirelessly.

Answer (score 0):

If your RPi2 is configured as an access point, it must be running dhcpd on it. You will have to configure BBB to connect to RPi's wifi network and make use of some server client program (Could be in any language) to exchange the data. It should not be very difficult if you know what you're doing. I suggest you to break things in part and conquer, like

1. If you're able to ping Rpi from BBB and vice versa to check your both wifi configuration.
2. Once done, how about taking TCP server client code from web and test it to exchange simple strings.

and so on...

Hope it helps.